# How can I force gnu ld to override the symbols in my own copy of a libc with the symbols from -lc?

Tags: c, linker, libc

I am porting uClibc to an rtos, which has as one of its' bsp targets the ability to run on top of posix.  Unfortunately, this means that when compiling for the posix target, if I link everything together as one binary executable, I get duplicate symbol errors between uClibc and the Linux system C library.

I would like to find a solution to this problem which would allow me to not have to hack the uClibc source while still allowing me to smoothly maintain the ability to compile for both the posix simulator and embedded relocatable image targets.  Is there some type of linker trick I can use to override the uClibc symbols with the equivalent glibc symbols at compile time if I need to?

Comment: At compile time you use #define's.  Proven, reliable work great, Also, try 'weak' functions, if your compiler & linker support this.

Comment: Thanks, weak symbols appear to be what I was looking for....